# Javascript Controlling Audio Tag in Background.html in a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, background, google-chrome-extension, popup

I would like to control the volume of an audio tag in a background page in a Chrome extension.
The media plays well but at a volume by default (I think it's 1 => max) however I can change the volume.

Do you know how to ?

*Background.html:*

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="http://radio-contact.ice.infomaniak.ch/radio-contact-high.mp3" id="radio" 
    autoplay="true" oncanplay="document.getElementById('radio').volume = 0.1">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

Moreover, I want to have Pause/Volume+/Volume- buttons in a popup.html to control it. 
I tried with chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage() but I can't control it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? posting the code you used may help.

Anyway, here is a simple code i tired and seems to work

***background.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function controlVolume(passedVolume)
{
    document.getElementById('radio').volume = passedVolume;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <audio src="http://radio-contact.ice.infomaniak.ch/radio-contact-high.mp3"
    id="radio" autoplay="true" oncanplay="controlVolume(0.1);">
    </audio>
</body>
</html>
```

***popup.html***

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input id="volume" type="text" />
<input type="button" value="change volume" onclick=
    "
        chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().controlVolume
               (document.getElementById('volume').value);
    "
/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I didn't work for me ! I'm in Chrome 18, so  I think it comes from Chrome !
I tried your code in a tab by launching background.html directly in the browser. It worked but in the extension it simply didn't want to work !
I tried the same thing as you but with buttons +/- and I can see that with an input it's the same !